# Why will it not open the desktop in the finder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

so I am creating a Siri type program and I am on Mac, when I speak into the mic and say hello it works no problem. But when I say 'Open Desktop' it doesn't open the desktop in the finder. I am really stuck so can someone please tell me what I have done wrong? I am using python2.7

Code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import os

speech = sr.Recognizer()

try:
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
except ImportError:
    print('Requested driver is not found')
except RuntimeError:
    print('Driver fails to initialize')

voices = engine.getProperty('voices')

engine.setProperty('voice', 'com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.Alex')
rate = engine.getProperty('rate')
engine.setProperty('rate', rate)


def speak_text_terminal(terminal):
    engine.say(terminal)
    engine.runAndWait()


def read_voice_terminal():
    voice_text = ''
    print('Listening: ')
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio = speech.listen(source)
    try:
        voice_text = speech.recognize_google(audio)
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        pass
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print('Network error!')
    return voice_text

if __name__ == '__main__':

    speak_text_terminal("Hello This is the AI! How can I help?")

    while True:

        voice_note = read_voice_terminal()
        print("terminal: {}".format(voice_note))

        if 'hello' in voice_note:
            speak_text_terminal("Hello How can i help you?")
            continue
        elif 'open' in voice_note:
            os.system('Finder C:// {}'.format(voice_note.replace('Open', '')))
            continue
        elif 'by' in voice_note:
            speak_text_terminal('Goodbye Mate!')
            exit()
```

Comment: `C://` is not the path to the desktop.

Comment: So what would it be?

Comment: @DanD. Can you help me out please?

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, your path is wrong and also the command:

```
os.system('open ~/Desktop/')
```

Edit: more complete solution:

```
os.system('open ~/{}'.format(voice_note.lower().replace('open', '').capitalize())
```

Comment: I have tried this but now whenever I say open like applications it just opens the desktop.. how do I get it so it opens whatever I say?? 
    os.system('open ~/Desktop/'.format(voice_note.replace('Open', ''))) 
@tayfun

Comment: @D.Denton Check the new version, adapt to your needs please.